# Will a clustered index improve performance of updates performed sequentially on that clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, index

I know indexes reduce data modification performance, but I have a task where (almost) all updates are done on items in a sequential order. Would a clustered index improve or reduce performance in updating these rows?

The clustered index would be on column `id` where `id` is an `IDENTITY` column. `id` is thus never changed and will be sequential (in addition rows should never be deleted). 
This is the format of my update statements:

```
UPDATE [table] SET value = 1 
WHERE  id IN (1,2,3,4...)
```

The values are not necessarily continous however. A sequence of `IN (1,2,4,5)` is also possible if `id=3` is not set to be updated, but they will always be in order.

**When all updates are in sequential order, will a clustered index improve or reduce performance?**

Comment: Is the choice just between no indexes and one clustered index on `id`? Do you have any other indexes on that table? Is `id` an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: @NickChammas No indexes yet and I don't have any known/suggested indexes to make. I can make any indexes I want on the table, and `id` is an `IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IN like this is a set of discrete values. SQL Server won't bother working out it is a range or checking ascending values.

That is, `x IN (1,2,4,5)` is parsed out to `x=1 OR x=2 OR x=4 OR x=5`. OR is non-SARGable in most cases and result in scans rather than seeks.

If you put the data into a temp table with an index and did `x IN (SELECT foo FROM #bar)` then it becomes a semi-join and will more likely use an index

Comment: do you mean add a index to temp table?

Comment: For an `IN` list on an indexed column you will typically get multiple seeks until the number of elements is around 60 then it will move to a scan with a join against a table of constants. [This is discussed in the comments here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx)